# Setup CodeIgniter site on Godaddy hosting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upload my code-igniter site on Godaddy hosting.
but getting 404 page not found error.

**Project structure**

> root/public_html/project

I am trying to access the project at www.site.com/project

**My .htacess file**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Important things in config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

**Important things in routes file**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
```

I have tried so many .htacess files and config edits but couldn't sort the issue out. Please help

Comment: If all of codeigniter files are in /project directory, your htaccess needs to know that I think. Try changing the last line to project/index.php

Comment: project is the main codeigniter project folder, its was working on localhost.
By the way I tried it, haven't fixed the error

Comment: Try change line to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]` (notice question mark).

Comment: The problem persists

Comment: Does it work with `index.php` in URL?

Comment: Enable query strings with proposal above.

Comment: it shows godaddy's file not found page with index.php in url

Comment: ok, enabling query strings changes the error. The error is

Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.

Comment: which directory is htaccess in?

Comment: Do you have `index()` method in `Main` controller?

Comment: htaccess file is in main folder (root folder)
Yes main controller have index()

Comment: Have you made sure that the controllers class and filename has there first letter uppercase?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, upper case first letter is the solution

Comment: why do I have to put the first letter in uppercase , in my localhost with xamp is working normally with lowercase????? =/

Comment: Seems like a problem with apache or the server that you are using, have you enabled the apache rewrite module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Model,Controller and other libraries  must start with a capital letter in codeigniter ( godaddy )

If you didnt make it work with .httacces , you should follow the new standars since codeigniter 2.x to 3.x ->.

Codeigniter 2.X

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Codeigniter 3.X

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/develop/user_guide_src/source/installation/upgrade_300.rst

Model,Controller and other libraries  must start with a capital letter.However, in some PHP servers like XAMPP  this is omitted, so in localhost you should get follow these changes. Just start to type uppercase your php classes.

> For example, if you have the following library file:
>
> application/libraries/mylibrary.php
>
> ... then you'll have to rename it to:
>
> application/libraries/Mylibrary.php
>
> The same goes for driver libraries and extensions and/or overrides of
> CodeIgniter's own libraries and core classes.
>
> application/libraries/MY_email.php      application/core/MY_log.php
>
> The above files should respectively be renamed to the following:
>
> application/libraries/MY_Email.php      application/core/MY_Log.php
>
> Controllers:
>
> application/controllers/welcome.php ->  application/controllers/Welcome.php
>
> Models:
>
> application/models/misc_model.php   ->  application/models/Misc_model.php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding, after `RewriteEngine On` in your htaccess file, the next line:

```
RewriteBase /project/
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime on live server .htaccess file may not work properly. try to upload it again if facing issue. i had this type of experience many times when moving codeigniter from local to live server.